# Relation between graphviz, the DOT format and cgraph?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I plan on using the DOT graph representation format to persist/serialize graphs with a bunch of attributes - not for the purposes of drawing them.

I got to know about DOT as in input format for [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/), so I went to that website to see how DOT gets parsed and whether I could use the parser or easily port it. What I found was this document: [Using GraphViz as a Library](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/libguide/libguide.pdf). Here's what it says about DOT:

> The cgraph library provides a parser for graphs represented in DOT.
> Using this, it is easy to read the graphs and query the desired
> attributes using agget or agxget . For more information on these
> functions, see Section 2.1.1.

and in Section 2.1.1 it says:

> The first step in drawing a graph is to create it.  To use the
> Graphviz layout software, the graph must be created using the `cgraph`
> library.
> We can create a graph in one of two main ways, using `agread()`
> or `agopen()` etc. etc.

... and then it describes those functions, which take a C-standard-library `FILE*`, or a `char*` string.

I don't quite get it. It looks like `cgraph` [is just a folder of code within the graphviz repository](https://github.com/ellson/graphviz/tree/master/lib/cgraph).

- What does it mean for a DOT file *not* to be read by the cgraph library?
- Does `cgraph` exist as a standalone library at all?
- Does the DOT format exist independently/is it developed independently of graphviz, and if so - is it independently related to the `cgraph` code?

Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2):

1. A dot file is simply a text file following a structure that desxribes a graph. Historically it was developed alongside GraphViz by AT&T back when "ma-bell" was in charge of the telephone network and developing inventions like the transistor, laser, etc. But dot files can now be read by many graph/network software packages.
2. cgraph is a library that comes with Graphviz. You can find it by looking for a file named that starts with the name libcgraph and is usually in a folder named lib. It can be used separately from GraphViz. The code for it is in the folder you saw.
3. technically dot and cgraph are separate things. Indeed Graphviz used to use a different library and switched to the cgraph library some time in the past. So you can find pdfs describing the older graphviz library on the graphviz website.

Think of Graphviz as the IDE/package/visualization system. cgraph is one tool in this package. Dot is the format for a text-based system for storing and manipulating graph data -- especially good for visualization.

Answer (score 1):

To your third questiom, DOT itself is just a language whose grammar allows one to describe graphs.  The various packages applications offer features like an IDE (e.g. GraphViz) and the ability to render and save the graphs in various formats and layouts.

If the grammar of the DOT language allows you to describe your graphs adequately, it's a great way to do that, because of the whole ecosystem of applications and renderers available, should you ever decide to use them.  And it is terse -- I use it for system documentation (>400 servers and >1000 nodes) for exactly this reason.